# How to Change Percentage Precision on Google Sheets Scatter Chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, formatting

[image: Pathway Length vs. Preparation Level]

I have made a scatter chart on Google Sheets from two columns of data. One column labeled "Pre-EO Remediation Rate" and one column labeled "Length of Pathway (Semesters)". A sample of the first three rows from each of these columns look like:

```
Pre-EO 1110 Remediation Rate
38.40%
50.50%
29.20%
```

```
Length of Pathway (Semesters)
3
2
4
```

How can I assure that the tickmarks on the y-axis of my scatter chart has labels "0%, 20%, 40%, 60%" instead of "0.00%, 20.00%, 40.00%, 60.00%" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the number format of your source data to not include any decimal places (the chart should inherit this change), or alternatively go to Chart editor/Customise/Vertical axis/Number format/Other custom formats and change to the '0%' format.

Comment: the "alternatively" option worked for me! You are a lifesaver!!!